# ReactJs TypeError default.a.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use `Auth0EditProfileWidget`

getting error at line 65:

```
this.form = React.render( <FormControl data={data} onSubmit={onSubmit} />, container );
```

> TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.render is not
>   a function

can anybody help me?

Edited: code

```js
import React            from 'react';
import formSerialize    from 'form-serialize';
import FieldTypeMapper  from './FieldTypes/FieldTypeMapper'

class FormFieldList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var fieldNodes = this.props.data.map( data => FieldTypeMapper(data.type)(data) );
    return ( <div>{fieldNodes}</div> );
  }
}

class ErrorItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <li>{this.props.message}</li> );
  }
}

class ErrorControl extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var errors = this.props.data.map( error => ( <ErrorItem key={error} message={error} /> ) );
    var style = {};

    if (errors.length === 0) {
      style.display = 'none';
    }

    return ( <ul className="error" style={style}>{errors}</ul> );
  }
}

class FormControl extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = props.data;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="editProfileForm">

          <ErrorControl data={this.state.errors} />

          <FormFieldList data={this.state.fields} />

          <input type="submit" value="Save" />

      </form>
    );
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = this.refs.editProfileForm.getDOMNode();
    var data = formSerialize(form, {hash: true});

    this.props.onSubmit(data);
  }
}

export default class EditProfileForm {
  constructor(container, data, onSubmit) {
    this.form = React.render( <FormControl data={data} onSubmit={onSubmit} />, container );
  }
  render(data) {
    this.form.setState(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post complete component for better understanding?

Comment: Feel like this is an import error but can't really say anything until we see some more code

Comment: i have edited the description with code

Comment: What's your react version?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fetchify": "0.0.2",
    "form-serialize": "^0.7.0",
    "highlight.js": "^9.15.6",
    "jquery": "3.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^1.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0"
  },

Comment: but when i comment out the function call:
var editProfileWidget = new Auth0EditProfileWidget('editProfileContainer', { domain: auth_domain },......

app works fine. no error about react render anywhere

Comment: the error is coming because its `ReactDOM.render()` not React.render()

Comment: just use this may be the error goes away `this.form = ( <FormControl data={data} onSubmit={onSubmit} />, container );`

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini no, because Target container is not a DOM element. and without render you cant see the form

Comment: can you share you code on codesandbox?

Comment: `React.render()` seems to be deprecated.

Comment: is `EditProfileForm` a React Component or a normal class ?

Comment: what command are you using to run your project

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your EditProfileForm class to this:

```
export default class EditProfileForm {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return(<FormControl data={this.props.data} onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit} />)
  }

}
```

And then call `ReactDom.render()` like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<EditProfileForm data={dataProp} onSubmit={onSubmitProp} />, container);
```

Comment: bro `EditProfileForm` does not look like the React component to me Because it do not extends React.Component

Comment: Oh yeah you are right, I missed that. Then can this even call `render()`? @Abhishek-Saini

Comment: that's exactly what I am thinking and ask her to share the whole code on codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class EditProfileForm {
    constructor(container, data, onSubmit) {
    this.form = React.render( <FormControl data={data} onSubmit={onSubmit} />, container );
    }
    render(data) {
    this.form.setState(data);
    }
}
```

things to note here, first, is `EditProfileForm` a react component or not because `EditProfileForm` do not extends `React.Component`

and Second thing is that `this.form.setState(data);` what is the value of `setState` why you use `this.form.setState()` what is it doing.